# Reading battery status for Windows CE based using win32 APIs

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, winapi

I am developing an application for Windows CE based devices to read battery status. How would I do using win32 APIs?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [GetSystemPowerStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453172.aspx).